# Data is not being written into SD card

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card

I want to save the file as date and time  and I want to open the file `mySensorData = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);` in the set up. It shows "insert SD card" when I try to open the file in setup.

The data is not being written into the SD card. It is creating the file but not writing into file.

Comment: and the first line `"Pressure, Temperature, Depth,Altitude"` is in the file?

Comment: in setup you open `"sensor1.txt"` and in loop `filename`. test `if (!mySensorData)`, not `if (mySensorData==0)`

Comment: Sorry! I just upload the new code.  I want to save the file as date and time .  and i want to open the file  mySensorData = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE); in the set up.  It shows insert SD card  when i try to open the file in setup .

Answer (score 1):

You start logging set to LOW and then test if it is high, since it isn't you go to the else clause, you call exit(0) and kill your processor, hence your code never gets executed!

```
volatile boolean logging = LOW;

...

void loop() 
{ 
   if(logging == HIGH) // starts low
   {
    ... // never executed
   }
   else 
   {
    ... // 
    exit(0); // now your Arduino is dead!
   }
}
```

The ellipses (...) are where i snipped your code out.

exit(0) turns off interrupts and loops forever with while(1); which has the effect of a full, power-consuming halt; exit(0) should have a sleep call in it, because what exit(...) does isn't very useful for an Arduino!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your answer. Would you please explain it to me .

Comment: @brar_kev I had stripped down the code to the structure so you can see; the first thing your loop does is check if (logging == HIGH) it was initialized it to LOW so flow goes to else clause, you do some stuff then you call exit(0) which halts the proccessor, the uC will not execute anymore instuctions until it is reset. so everything else never gets called.

Comment: But in the interrupts logging = ! logging .. so i'm making it low .. The code was working fine but when i added the RTC module then it stopped writing into the file. I checked when try to open the file in the set up the it shows iNSERT sd CARD AND  if i comment the open file section then it works . I'm  new to programming  and don't know how should i change it now .Thank for help

Comment: @brar_kev exit(0) disables interrupts, so your interrupt handler can't be executed either.

Comment: How should i proceed now ?  I'm stuck don't know what should i change to make it work

Comment: @brar_kev sorry if it wasn't obvious, but remove the exit(0) and see how it works then.

Comment: I removed that one and it still printing Insert SD card .

Comment: do the samples work? also SD.begin(4) should only be called once; remove it from the while loop in setup

Comment: I tried the Sd examples and they are working perfectly fine. I removed the SD.begin from while loop and it's still showing Insert Sd card. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: Anybody knows .. What should i do ?? I'm stuck

Comment: @brar_kev start with the sample, and add pieces to it until it works or something breaks, whatever breaks may tell you what is broken, or a better question to ask

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to memory . So i commented some Serial.print commands and then it worked perfectly fine . I edit this part  of my code .

else 
   {
//    Serial.print(mySensorData);
//    Serial.println("Insert SD card for logging");
    digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Insert SD card");
    delay(1000);
//
   }

Comment: Please list the lines that you had to comment out. Your answer may help someone with the same problem.